# Clearing a div in Jquery using its i.d

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to remove the user input and replace it with the original placeholder by using the `empty()` function.

Here is the jQuery file which takes input from user through a `<form>` and appends it to list with the `template()` structure:

```
var template = function(text) {
  return '<p><input type="checkbox"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i><span>' + text + '</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></p>';
};

var main = function() {
  $('.form').submit(function() {
        var text = $('#todo').val();
        var html = template(text);
        $('.list').append(html);
        $('#todo').empty();
        return false;
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

After the user submits their text and it is added to the list I want the 'form' input to empty so you can enter a new item with out deleting what you just typed.

Here is a snippet of the html file that jQuery is interacting with:

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-container">
    <input id="todo" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Add item">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">+</button>
</form>
```

Why is the line

```
$('#todo').empty();
```

not removing the user input and returning it to the original placeholder?

Comment: just trigger reset on the form so it will wok for later too when you have multiple and different inputs on the form. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty method doesn't delete the attributes or values but it removes the html inside an element. You should use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$('#todo').val('');//To empty the value
```

If you want to remove the placeholder too then use [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) method:

```
$('#todo').removeAttr('placeholder');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('form').trigger("reset");
```

This is the **most elegant and correct way** since it will work when you have multiple and different type of inputs without needing to do any changes. Much better than trying to empty and resetting placehorders on all fields. This will make sure to set the fields to initial state (having placeholders set too).

Based on your code you could do:

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
    // ...
    $(this).trigger("reset");
    // ...
});
```

See it working on an example form based on yours with more fields `input`s and `select` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/5r0s6djx/).

See JQuery reset Doc here: [JQuery API Doc/reset](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

`.empty()` is for other use cases. From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)...

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Instead, you can `.val('')` your `<input />`. Observe the following simplified example...

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
    $('#todo').val('');
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yh61nLse/) - demo

---

as an observation to your neighboring code you can also pass the `event` and call `.preventDefault()` in place of `return false;`. Alternatively, you can  call [reset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) in your function block as such: `this.reset()` - [**reset demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uy0w2tfa/) with default behavior prevented.